# delete confirmation message on anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

As a new learner, i have some basic problems which i want to clear out.
1)i have shown student data, in tabular format.
2)in the last  of below code i have provided two anchor tags.
3)among them first one redirects on update page whether the second one directly executes delete query on click without confirmation).
so what i want ,when i click on delete link, browser should ask me for confirmation,
if yes,
then delete and redirect to login page.
if no,
stay on same page

```
        >>    <tr>
          <td><?php echo $result['id']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $result['sname'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $result['class']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $result['gname'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $result['contact']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $result['gender']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $result['email'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $result['bloodg']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $result['address']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $result['division'];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $result['shift']; ?></td>
          <td>
            <a class= "action-e" href= "update.php?id=<?php echo $result['id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-wrench" title="Update"></i></a>
            <a class= "action-d" href= "delete.php?id=<?php echo $result['id'] ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash" title="Delete"></i></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: No need to write the entire Title in CAPS, it's considered shouting and could result in less people wanting to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <tr>
      <td><?php echo $result['id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result['sname'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result['class']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result['gname'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result['contact']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result['gender']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result['email'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result['bloodg']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result['address']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result['division'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result['shift']; ?></td>
      <td>
        <a class="action-e" href="update.php?id=<?php echo $result['id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-wrench" title="Update"></i></a>
        <a class="action-d" href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $result['id'] ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"><i class="fa fa-trash" title="Delete"></i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Please consider leaving a comment in your answer explaining why your answer solves the OP's problem.